# How do I groupby then unstack a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get the [Atr.] values as columns with one date per row, but I'm having a lot of issues with the df.unstack() method. Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTTkU.png)

Expected output:

| Date | Attribute #1 | Attribute #2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Date #1 | value | value |
| Date #2 | value | Value |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)